# Rsnapshot remote backup_script execution using non standard ssh port and key?

Tags: rsnapshot

Using rsnapshot to backup a remote host with a **non-standard ssh port** (:444)

rsnapshot.conf setup:

```
ssh_args        -p444
backup  user@domain:/data/location/       vps2/site/
```

**OK**, no issue on port 444 for "normal" backup.

Issues are on backup_script execution to dump mysql:

```
backup_script   ssh user@domain "/scripts/dumpscript" Unused/
OR
backup_script   ssh user@domain "/scripts/dumpscript" Unused/ +ssh_args=-p444
OR
backup_script   ssh user@domain "/scripts/dumpscript" Unused/ +ssh_args=-P 444
```

**KO error 255**, command is executed on port 22 (+ssh_args=-p444 or -P 444 seems ignored).

*ssh user@domain -p 444 "scripts/dumpscript"* launched directly from a shell outside of rsnapshot is OK.

```
backup_script   scp -r -P 444 user@domain:/tmp/rsnapshot/mysql/ /c/snapshot/tmp/        dump/
```

**OK**, no issue with scp on port 444

Any idea on **how to correctly setup port:** for backup_script to ssh remote script execution ? Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Finally, and simply !!! :

```
backup_script  ssh -p444 user@domain "/scripts/dumpscript" Unused/
```

**OK** (tabs only after backup_script and before Unused/)

And if needed to specify certificate location:

```
backup_script ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_root -p444 user@domain "/scripts/dumpscript" Unused/
```

**OK** (tabs only after backup_script and before Unused/)

And, For normal "backups points" **ssh_args=** after destination directory is required:

```
backup   user@domain:/var/www/   destination/  ssh_args=-i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_root -p444
```

**OK** (tabs after backup, source and destination)